# How to plot a distribution function in matplotlib if input data has has two options of distribution that can be followed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot graph b/w x1(and x2) and f where f is the the distribution function. I want to know that my input data x1 and x2 are following which one the  two distribution functions? So how should I plot graph for this purpose?

```
`#Input data
x1=np.array([0.433172   0.48298582 0.92493727 2.15890491])
x2 = np.array([0.22727232 0.52651793 1.51814772 1.72806203])
f = np.exp(-x) #Poisson-distribution
f =  x*np.pi/2.*np.exp(-x*x*np.pi/4) #WD distribution
```

On y-axis I have to plot distribution function. I want to check which distribution my input data is following. But if I mention formula of any distribution suppose Poisson distribution the I'will force my data to follow this specif distribution that I don't want. So how can I do that?

Comment: Hi jerry. Your data distribution is dependent on what you mention? Sounds weird. You could include your plots and an example set of data to attract more folks who can answer.

Comment: No it is not dependent It can be either poission or wigner-Dyson.x-axis it is x and on y-axis it can be either P(x) = exp(-x) or wigner-dyson. So what should I do to plot the graph